# How to temporarily block network access to root user?

Tags: networking, security

Just want to temporarily block network access sometimes, even to the root user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your firewall to block everything.

To Block All (For All Users Including Root):

`sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP`

`sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP`

`sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP`

To Allow Again:

`sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`